# Prettyphoto javascript opens blank page with 'false' in firefox

Tags: javascript, xml, flash, firefox, prettyphoto

I'm using this click function to open prettyphoto in iframe mode:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.fn.prettyPhoto();
  $('a').click(function(){
     window.$.prettyPhoto.open($(this).attr('src'), $(this).attr('title'), attr('desc'));

   social_tools: false

      return false;
  });
});
```

and calling it like this:

```
a href="javascript:$.prettyPhoto.open('http://mypage.com?iframe=true=true&width=820&height=700', 'title', 'desc'');">test</a>
```

which works fine in Chrome and Safari but in Firefox I get a blank page showing just the word 'false' and the full url 'javascript:$.prettyPhoto.open('http://mypage.com?iframe=true=true&width=820&height=700' in the address bar.

I'm restricted using the 'click' function because the link is in an xml for Flash and Flash doesn't support the rel attribute. I'm fairly sure that this worked previously in firefox so I think it may only be an issue in the latest version which I recently downloaded.

Can anyone help please? :)

Comment: move code from `href` to `onclick` attribute like this: <a href="#" onclick="javascript code without `javascript:` prefix">link</a>

Comment: Thanks for the reply Omid. Unfortunately I'm stuck with using the href because the link is on an xml file which generates the content in flash. I'm using flash maps from ammap.com, the site was built before they stopped supporting flash maps so can't change the way they're built. The href works in other browsers so I'm sure there must be some trick to getting it to work in firefox.

Comment: this is bug after `firefox v6`,you can't run javascript in url. can you give event on click `a` element with native javascript or jquery? if yes,you can prevent default action and run code in href attribute.

Comment: I think this would require adding a class to the a element, which I can't do either because I don't have the fla source file. I will see if I can get ammaps to help out from here. Thanks so much for your help Omid :)

Comment: i suggest bind event listener  `onclick` for all `a` tag and if you give click event from `a` on flash link, we try to limit and customize code for handle `a` tag only you want.